# std::length_error at memory location When using SFML RenderWindow

Tags: c++, sfml

I am using **[SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/)** for my project and I am currently following the tutorials on the site.

Currently I have only got to the first step of creating a **[RenderWindow](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1RenderWindow.php)** using the following code (pasted directly from the tutorial) :

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/RenderWindow.hpp>

int main()
{
    // create the window
    sf::VideoMode vm (800, 600);
    sf::RenderWindow window(vm, "My window");

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        // clear the window with black color
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        // draw everything here...
        // window.draw(...);

        // end the current frame
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine, however when I run it I get the following exception :

```
First-chance exception at 0x76BFC42D in OpenGlTest.exe: Microsoft C++ 
exception: std::length_error at memory location 0x0046F754.
```

I tried debugging and traced the std::length_error to the RenderWindow constructor :

```
sf::RenderWindow window(vm, "My window");
```

I am very inexperienced with c++ and OpenGL so I do not know how to proceed further, it will not let me step into the constructor to see what is happening, it just throws the exception immediately.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which version of the library did you download (ex. Visual C++ 13 (32-bit) )? What are you building for (32-bit, 64-bit) and what VS are you using?

Comment: Downloaded 32-bit for sfml and I'm fairly sure it's building for 32-bit. For reference, where would I check what it's building for in Visual C++ 2013 ?

Comment: Usually beside where you select "Release" vs "Debug", you can specify machine configuration (32-bit is Win32 which should be default). Otherwise you can check "Project Properties" and in the Platform Dropdown.

Comment: Can your SFML libraries be found (that is, are they beside your binary or in the DLL search path)?

Comment: I've added the path for the lib folder into the Additional Library Directories under "Linker" in properties if that's what you mean. Should I also add them next to the binary ? I also added them into the "Additional Dependencies".

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the problem. I'm not sure if this is a fix or just luck but apparently crashes can occur if you link to sfml-xxxx.lib instead of sfml-xxxx-d.lib when using Visual C++. It does seem to work after that change.

Comment: That's the debug build. You probably have to match it (i dont remember having to worry about that). So when you build Release, you should make sure you link to the non 'd' version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with SFML, but when you craete a window like that, there are the windows buttons, and they take much more than 10 pixels together.

Have you tried to increase the size?
Try with 200, like the tutorial does.

Comment: Yeah I changed that when it was broken to test something, should have mentioned. It's still broken on the normal resolution unfortunately :(. Corrected the code now.